# clear previous measurement result in labview

Tags: labview

I try to measure noise for 3s period to find out the maximum value each time. the problem is that the previous measurement results remained in the block (maybe because of iteration). I need help to clear all values belong to previous measurement when click to start button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it done programatically this [link](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/5B0B282E31E65E42862577A7005BC9AA) may be helpful.

You can always perform such action manually by right clicking on chart and in context menu there should be an option clear graph/chart.

Comment: chart is just for demonstration. I need to clear the blocks which assess the measurement result against a limit such as Ok or Not Ok.

Comment: Then I belive this one will be the sollution: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/08E7DDAE66A7D02C86256DDA00630E75